# What statistical test should I use to look for a significant change across a series of growth rings?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

[image: Image shows estimated point (by eyeball) at which maturity may occur]I am looking to identify when a significant change occurs across a series of growth rings (annuli) of fish pectoral fins. I am trying to identify when the annuli width decreases (state of maturity). I will have the widths of each growth ring (um) across the structure.

After I determine state of maturity I want to compare the trace elemental compositions before and after. I have ablated a line to quantify 13 trace elemts across the fin ray from the core to the outer edge, ensuring a
consistent and distinguishable signature corresponding
with each growth band. I am considering using an interupted time series regression to compare before and after maturity. Does this sound like a good way to go?
[image: example of trace elemental profiles across the fin ray]

Third image shows [image: same as image 1 (different fish)]

Comment: Is there anything special about the fact that they’re rings, or is it just a matter of growing $2\mu$m, $2\mu$m, $2\mu$m, and then $1\mu$m?

Comment: can you post a plot of typical data that show the point at which you would say (by eyeball) that maturity occurs?  A *changepoint model* might be appropriate.

Comment: Over how many years do you have data. The difference between 5 and 15 might make a difference in the most transparent analysis.

Comment: @BruceET, the fish are anywhere from 15-60 years old.